# Vectorize python code for improved performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, scientific-computing

I am writing a scientific code in python to calculate the energy of a system.
Here is my function : cte1, cte2, cte3, cte4 are constants previously computed; pii is np.pi (calculated beforehand, since it slows the loop otherwise). I calculate the 3 components of the total energy, then sum them up.

```
def calc_energy(diam): 
    Energy1 = cte2*((pii*diam**2/4)*t)
    Energy2 = cte4*(pii*diam)*t
    d=diam/t
    u=np.sqrt((d)**2/(1+d**2))
    cc= u**2
    E = sp.special.ellipe(cc) 
    K = sp.special.ellipk(cc) 
    Id=cte3*d*(d**2+(1-d**2)*E/u-K/u)
    Energy3 = cte*t**3*Id
    total_energy = Energy1+Energy2+Energy3
    return (total_energy,Energy1)
```

My first idea was to simply loop over all values of the diameter :

```
start_diam, stop_diam, step_diam = 1e-10, 500e-6, 1e-9 #Diametre
diametres = np.arange(start_diam,stop_diam,step_diam)

for d in diametres:  
    res1,res2 = calc_energy(d)
    totalEnergy.append(res1)
    Energy1.append(res2)
```

In an attempt to speed up calculations, I decided to use numpy to vectorize, as shown below :

```
diams = diametres.reshape(-1,1) #If not reshaped, calculations won't run
r1 = np.apply_along_axis(calc_energy,1,diams)
```

However, the "vectorized" solution does not properly work. When timing I get 5 seconds for the first solution and 18 seconds for the second one.

I guess I'm doing something the wrong way but can't figure out what.

Comment: Is there a difference between the function calc_total_energy you are calling and calc_energy you are defining

Comment: I have tried to Cythonize my code. With very few changes I got a 40 to 50% increase in performance. However, I guess I could get an equivalent improvement by simply vectorizing

Comment: To vectorize this, you'd want to avoid applying the function across each item in the array since that has all the overhead of Python. Instead, you can carry out the calculations in bulk e.g. `Energy1 = cte2*((pii*diametres**2/4)*t)` will give you back an array of `Energy1` values.

Comment: Your function `calc_energy`, as is, will accept `diametres`, the array, as an input without modification. Does that give you the correct output? I have no way to sanity check whether it's giving the right values.

Comment: @roganjosh, yep, i just checked it `calc_energy(diametres)` - will return arrays that will produce the same sum's. I think you should post it as an answer

Comment: How would `np.pi` be slower to access than `pii`? Have you done any types of measurements?

Comment: Sorry I was away from computer. The solution works. It now computes in less than 0.1 second instead of 5 ! Great performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current approach, you're applying a Python function to each element of your array, which carries additional overhead. Instead, you can pass the whole array to your function and get an array of answers back. Your existing function appears to work fine without any modification.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special
cte = 2
cte1 = 2
cte2 = 2
cte3 = 2
cte4 = 2
pii = np.pi

t = 2

def calc_energy(diam): 
    Energy1 = cte2*((pii*diam**2/4)*t)
    Energy2 = cte4*(pii*diam)*t
    d=diam/t
    u=np.sqrt((d)**2/(1+d**2))
    cc= u**2
    E = special.ellipe(cc) 
    K = special.ellipk(cc) 
    Id=cte3*d*(d**2+(1-d**2)*E/u-K/u)
    Energy3 = cte*t**3*Id
    total_energy = Energy1+Energy2+Energy3
    return (total_energy,Energy1)

start_diam, stop_diam, step_diam = 1e-10, 500e-6, 1e-9 #Diametre
diametres = np.arange(start_diam,stop_diam,step_diam)

a = calc_energy(diametres) # Pass the whole array
```